# File uploading via FTP from Client machine IIS to Server machine IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload, ftp

We have a asp website to upload files Client machine(website hosted in IIS) to Server machine(website hosted in IIS) using FTP. Both client and server websites are different websites. Our clients may use any of the windows OS (i.e. XP, Win 7, Win server 2003/2008).

While testing the file upload using FTP, we sent files in various sizes from almost all the OS. Issue is, i can able to upload files only within size of 512MB through FTP (using HTML input control) from Win 7 & Win server 2008 to xp, win 7, server 2008 and if i try more 512 MB, then it throws me **System.out of memory exception** and in same manner only i can upload files within size of 64MB from Win XP to xp, win 7, Win server 2008 and if i try more than 64 MB, it throws me **System.out of memory exception**.

I need a two solution :

1) I confused at above uploading....... why i can only upload within 64 MB file From XP to any OS?(which includes XP, Win 7, Server 2008). but from Win 7& Win server 2008 to any OS i can upload upto 512MB files.

2) If i try more than 512MB 0r 64MB files it throws **System.out of memory exception**.?

Please advise on solving this problem.

I have following settings in my website's web.config file,

```
    <system.web>
           <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="50000" />
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
     <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
```

please help me.

Thanks,

Kaviyarasan

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Error/Exception, it seems that its not an issue from ASP.NET. Its more of a Memory issue.

Because you've already set the Execution Timeout Time and Max Content size in your web.config file. So, I guess there is no problem at all.

But if possible, try to check the Thread [enter link description here](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/2642879-maximum-upload-size-in-asp-net-is-2gb-increase-it).  You might get what you want. This is the same for your problem No 2.

Comment: From windows 7 and win server 2008 to other OS i can upload upto 512MB files but why i can't send more than 64MB files from Win XP to other OS. 
XP Configuration : 
     XP machine has 4 GB ram memory, Service Pack 3. No other bulk processes was running in XP (in parallel) while trying the upload.
 (Note : we are using .NET Framework 2.0/3.5).